# Ubuntu script that runs commands after su - user

Tags: command-line, gnome, scripts, gnome-shell, su

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-31-generic x86_64)

GNOME Shell 3.28.4

GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Typically, `su - user`  is called in a terminal and the user then types in more commands but in my case, I'm writing **a script** that needs to log into a user (there would be `username@pcname:~$` in front of every line, not sure if you call that log in), and then run the commands that would normally be typed

I need to do this because these commands are `sudo apt install` ed in my user and don't seem to work whenever there's no `username@pcname:~$` at the beginning of each lines

I know that there's a `-c` flag. But as far as I can tell, `-c` flag just runs the commands under `su` as I'm getting `-su: MyCommand: command not found`.

```
su - Username -c "some_commands;some_other_commands"
```

Is su - User the right way to achieve this? (`username@pcname:~$`) What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

BTW, this was previously asking about how to write a script to do this, but It was getting overcomplicated specific and confusing so I'm narrowing it down to this problem.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to execute it *in a login shell*, rather than to actually log in again. Also I don't understand why you need to invoke `gnome-terminal` explicitly when you are already setting `Terminal=true`. So maybe try `Exec=bash -lc "cd ~/gdrive; drive init; drive pull --no-prompt -ignore-conflict"` ?

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks! but now this is weird because when it is a login shell, echo $0 should output `-bash` instead of `bash`, but when I added that before `cd~/gdrive` and ran it, it outputs `bash`. Do you have any idea as to why? Thanks again!

Comment: wait, I just realized that `echo $0` in a normal terminal also returns `bash`, s the issue is not the login shell. it's just that the commands need to run as my user `Kenivia@hi:~$` after `su - Kenivia`

Comment: Would you not already be logged in as your user before running *"a desktop click-to-run script"*? or are you logging in to your desktop session as a different user for some reason?

Comment: @steeldriver sorry, that's not what I meant. I meant that the terminal does not have the `Kenivia@hi:~$` in front of the lines. I don't know what to call that

Answer (score 1):

When my regular user desktop needs to run a script requiring `sudo` I create an entry like this:

[image: eyesome desktop entry.png]

Then I write a wrapper script within the path to elevate to `sudo` level:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/eyesome-cfg-desktop-wrapper.sh

#!/bin/bash

# NAME: eyesome-cfg-desktop-wrapper.sh
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Wrapper script to call `eyesome-cfg.sh`
# DATE: Sep 24, 2018. Modified June 6, 2019

# NOTE: Designed to be called from ~/Desktop/eyesome-cfg.desktop

# UPDT: 2019-06-06 Name change to reflect wrapper script.

PROGNAME="eyesome-cfg.sh"

tty -s;
if [[ "0" == "$?" ]]; then
    echo "$PROGNAME cannot be called from background process."
    exit 1
fi

if [[ $EUID != 0 ]]; then

    # Get sudo password
    Password=$(zenity --password --title="Password for $PROGNAME")
    encryptPassword=$(echo -n "$Password" | md5sum)

    # After viewing encrypted password once, comment out line below.
    # echo "md5sum: $encryptPassword" 

    # Set value in quotes below to encryped password revealed above.
    if [[ "$encryptPassword" != "005e160c7bcfacf3d818d66e5856d75a  -" ]]; then
        echo "Invalid password!"
        exit 1
    fi

fi # non-terminals can't enter password.

# Call eyesome-cfg.sh with any parameters passed to this wrapper sript
if [[ $EUID == 0 ]]; then
    sudo "$PROGNAME" "$@" # Already running as sudo.
else
    echo $Password | sudo -S "$PROGNAME" "$@"
fi

exit 0
```

Note the first time you run the script remove the comment (`#`) on this line:

```
    # echo "md5sum: $encryptPassword"
```

Then the script will display your encrypted password. Take that encrypted password and enter it a couple lines below:

```
    if [[ "$encryptPassword" != "005e160c7bcfacf3d818d66e5856d75a  -" ]]; then
```

Of course this is all optional and you can skip encryption and have your password coded into the script in regular text for anyone to read. But I wouldn't do that...

Comment: Thanks! but this only runs the command with sudo privileges, but still doesn't make `username@pcname:~$` to appear in front of the script that I run.

Comment: @Kenivia I just included by setup as a template to show how to substitute user (sudo) from the desktop. Also how to encrypt the password to ensure it is correct before calling sudo. For your purposes the script needs to be modified a little bit. Having only one user account I was unable to test any changes to the script.